# Duplicated blocks in SonarQube between POJOs

Tags: java, sonarqube

How to ignore duplicated blocks in SonarQube for getters/setters in POJOs?

Example:

```
@Entity
public class Clazz {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String abc;
}

public class ClazzDTO {
    private int id;
    private String abc;
}
```

Comment: Please add an example to show what you mean and also what have you tried so far

Comment: Use Inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues

It gives detailed information on how to ignore certain rules for certain files in SonarQube.

Best way is to have all the POJOs under a package (eg 'model') and exclude that package from the Sonar scanning.